# Python: No Module Named src

Tags: python

I am developing an app with all of the modules in directory `src` and files for testing inside a directory  called `test`, both within the `myproject` directory.  When I run pytest, I get a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'.

My project directory structure

```
myproject
|
 --src
   |
   -- __init__.py
   -- module1.py
   -- module2.py
|
 --test
   |
   --test_module1.py
```

_*init_*.py is empty.
`test_module1.py` has the following import statement:
`from src.module1 import myfunc`

When I run pytest, I get a ModuleNotFoundError (full traceback below), saying that there is no module called src.  Do I need to import the modules into init.py for this to work?

sys.path includes `/Users/xxx/projects/myproject` as the first line.

Full traceback:

```
ImportError while importing test module '/Users/xxx/projects/myproject/test/test_module1.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
test/first_test.py:3: in <module>
    import src.first as m
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

Comment: You need to insert the project directory in `sys.path`. Try printing `sys.path` and you'll see if can't find the `src` directory because it's not in the path: only the `test` directory is.

Comment: `from ..src.module1 import myfunc` . `src` isn't in `test` so you need to tell it to back up `..` one directory first

Comment: Use `$ python -m site` to conveniently show the contents of `sys.path`. Adjust the PYTHONPATH env var to affect that path. Or perhaps chdir to the right place before invoking the interpreter, so that `.` in the path will be effective.

Comment: @AlexHuszagh and @J_H -  The `myproject` directory is in sys.path.  I am updating the question to reflect that.